# Why my private channels are always empty in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

**The problem**

In the *Discuss* menu, you can see your chats. They are grouped by:

- Channels.
- Direct messages.
- Private channels.

If I go to any channel and write anything, I can see what I've just written (like the people which can read that channel). This is the normal behaviour, and it should happen the same with the other two categories. However, if I do the same action but in a private channel or sending a direct message, the screen remains empty: I can't see what I've just written, and the people who receive the message neither.

**My attempts to solve it**

I've compared a standard channel to a private channel, and the user configuration of both is the same.

I've checked the longpolling port but I think that's not the problem because if so, no channel would be working.

I've also updated `base` and `mail` modules with no result.

Honestly, I have no idea of what to do, this is happening in a specific server, in other ones I have everything works fine. I'm trying to compare all but it's taking me a long time, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution:

Each time you create a new channel or send a direct message to any user (chat), a record is generated in the `mail_channel` table. You can see them through the interface if you activate technical settings and go to *Settings > Technical > Email > Channels*.

In this model, there is a field named `message_followers_ids`, which is an One2many pointing to the model `mail.followers`.

My problem (which was due to a 3rd party module I had installed) was that the channels were created with no followers, so the messages were not shown.

For example, I've created a new private channel named `test`. When this is created, a record is created in `mail.channel` and `mail.followers` models, but there was no link between them (it was created with no followers), so, when I wrote a message, I wasn't able to see it, take a look at the `mail.followers` record:

```
  id  | partner_id | channel_id |        res_model         | res_id 
------+------------+------------+--------------------------+--------
 1037 |            |            | mail.channel             |
```

But then, I've added the record created in `mail.followers` to the `message_followers_ids` field of the channel:

```
  id  | partner_id | channel_id |        res_model         | res_id 
------+------------+------------+--------------------------+--------
 1037 |            |         65 | mail.channel             |     65
```

After this, it started to work OK again.

As a curiosity, if you have another channel named `replica` for example, and you set it as a follower of the `test` channel, every message written in `test` will be shown in `replica`, but not the other way round.